# Display a slide menu on a grapphopper map in android

Tags: android, slide, mapsforge

Hello everybody i'm actually working on an android a app using a grapphopper map and i want to display a slide menu on it but it doesn't display anything unfortunately except the map eventhough the slide menu works in another simple activity, so could someone suggest a solution please?

Comment: First of all GraphHopper is a routing library not a map. Are you using mapsforge map? Please post your code.

Comment: yes i'm using mapforge

Comment: Please post relevant code + layout.